# Scala and Mockito: keyword "then" is deprecated

Tags: scala, mockito

Future versions of Scala may use `then` as a keyword, as stated in [SIP-12](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/uncluttering-control.html).

The compiler already shows a warning for it:

> Usage of then as identifier is deprecated. It can be used as a keyword in future versions of scala.
>   Word then is reserved as a possible keyword in future versions of scala. It’s usage as identifier is deprecated. See SIP-12.

I'm using Mockito and have many occurrences of `then` methods called.

```
BDDMockito.then(entityService).should(Mockito.times(2)).findBy(any)
```

Does anyone know if there's an alternative to replace it?

Comment: The SIP page that you link to also says this: *"The committee votes unanimously to reject the change."* And that decision is from 2016. Weird that you are getting warnings about `then`.

Comment: @Lii: Yes, it's true. But there's a long discussion on [this thread](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/the-state-of-then/1638) where it seems this was added without approval. I can see this on my compiler. Hopefully they remove the validation soon (or apply it for real).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scala, wrapping any identifier in backticks "`" prevents it from being treated as a keyword.

```
BDDMockito.`then`(entityService).should(Mockito.times(2)).findBy(any)
```

This has most commonly been used to allow fields/variables/methods to be named `type`, but it should work for `then` as well.  It's also sometimes used to embed spaces into identifiers.

```
case class Bar(`class`: Int, `type`: String) {
  def `class with type`: String = s"${`class`}_${`type`}"
}

Bar(42, "skidoo").`class with type` == "42_skidoo"
```

Comment: It should be noted that this technique can readily be abused to create unreadable code, and the most defensible use is exactly this: when you depend on a library which has used a Scala keyword as a method/field name, and perhaps when practicing "schema-centric development" where you'd prefer to have `type`/`class`/`object` as schema fields and also want some sort of automatic mapping of case classes to the schema definition (e.g. macro-based type class derivation or reflection).  Beyond that, (as in the second example), this technique is one to keep for "obfuscated scala" contests!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala)? its API is tailored for Scala and it caters for all the language features that the Java version doesn't

Comment: Thank you @Bruno. I will consider that.